# Format repeating header for columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I want to generate a html and CSS for print.

I want kind of this result:

[image]

What are the requirements?

1. The text which overflows at the bottom of box 1 should continue in box 2
2. Before the text in box 2 continues i want to add an element. In this case Heading should be added
3. The text is has an variable size. The text is fetched from a database and varies in size and styling. So I can't predict were the element should start in the box 2
4. Over these 2 boxes are other elements which reduce the size of these boxes even further
5. The printed pagesize is A4

**What I tried:**

I tried this with `columns:2` property in css, but I can't detect when the column ends and starts a new one(as far as I know).

I used the pseudeselector `:before` to add content to this div.
I would like some selector like `column:beforeColumnBreak`. I know this selector doesn't exist, but I hope it brings the idea accross.

I tried Bootstrap with rows and columns.

Has someone experienced solutions with print? Is there maybe a JS-libary which can help me with this problem?

#####EDIT 1

The Problem is due to the fact that web doesn't know any pages.

NEW PAGE is when a new A4 side starts. So when the text overflows.
The text should continue like this 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
In each box should the heading element be present.

[image]

Comment: always 2 columns?

Comment: For my case the answer is yes

Comment: so why not having two header at the start and each one will simply take 50% of width then you have your columns

Comment: I will add an Image for futher explanation. Hang on.